# Move image randomly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code that supposedly makes the image move around the page but It doesnt moves can someone identify the error.

Thanks.

#### My HTML :

```
<div id="container"> <span id="random"><img src="poke.png"></span> </div>
```

#### My JS :

```
<script>
function moveDiv() {
    var $span = $("#random");

    $span.fadeOut(270, function() {
        var maxLeft = $(window).width() - $span.width();
        var maxTop = $(window).height() - $span.height();
        var leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxLeft + 1))
        var topPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxTop + 1))

        $span.css({ left: leftPos, top: topPos }).fadeIn(270);
    });
};

moveDiv();
setInterval(moveDiv, 270);
</script>
```

#### My CSS :

```
<style>span { display: inline-block; position: absolute;}</style>
```

Comment: wrap the code inside `$(document).ready function

Comment: or wrap it in $(function(){ //your code here });

Comment: its working here https://jsfiddle.net/yfbndkr3/

Comment: Works fine for me, what error are you getting? - https://jsfiddle.net/nmkkcwpw/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try with below code, it might help you.

```js
function moveDiv() {
    var $span = $("#random");

    $span.fadeOut(270, function() {
        var maxLeft = $(window).width() - $span.width();
        var maxTop = $(window).height() - $span.height();
        var leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxLeft + 1))
        var topPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxTop + 1))

        $span.css({ left: leftPos, top: topPos }).fadeIn(270);
    });
};

moveDiv();
setInterval(moveDiv, 270);
```

```css
span { display: inline-block; position: absolute;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"> <span id="random"><img src="http://hiroki.jp/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/google-chrome-logo-100x100.png"></span> </div>
```

Comment: you have written Jquery but not linked its library link it and will work.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [**here**](https://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/VeNzZG) your code works fine. The reason why in  your case the code is not working is beacuse the script is not running when all of the DOM is loaded.

You can wrap your script code in document ready

`$(document).ready()`

Like the above comments mentioned, this ensures the code is ran when the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

[It works](http://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/CYk7H/12/) just include the jQuery into your code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can wrap your script code in document ready too.

```
$(document).ready()
```